Have a google form that I need duplicate responses filtered out but a total count, but also have a
I have a google form that I am making for a friend that he is using to get feedback on game suggestions. The form is simple, game name and a weblink if possible.
What I am looking to do is have the list in google sheets, and then condense the list down to just show 1 instance per entry but to get a total count. However at the same time we need to have a drop down list to show approved, maybe and rejected. Pivot table doesn't work since there is no way in the same view to mark the approved, maybe or rejected, since it dynamic.  Was wondering if anyone might have an idea on a script that might work similar to a pivot table but allow a column with a drop down menu?
For example:



Game
Weblink
Total
Approved?




Uno
Amazonblahblah
4
Approved


Monopoly
Amazonblahblah
2
Rejected



If at all possible need the ability to marked approved or not on the condensed list.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1erj--xobXXHaM7TULruhx8lsCEWgLG7oU2q3Z3_vl4Y/edit?usp=sharing
Link to sheet if that would help.
I have basically 0 coding knowledge but have figured out in the past how to use the script editor in google sheets and found coding on this site that I have been able to modify for other uses so I can sort of read/understand basic coding.
I tried using pivot tables, and messed around with drop menus but couldn't get anything to work

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Hi!
I think I got what you wanted, Here is the form link:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdFzKywS-A-Pkiuds-x7R29Gl6dZyKJLip2wD63b0YbuHDqLw/viewform
and here is the google doc with a tab that show expected outcome:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1erj--xobXXHaM7TULruhx8lsCEWgLG7oU2q3Z3_vl4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Something I forgot to mention is if possible an easy way for the list to update itself with new entries, as this list will be added to over time.

Please add any relevant information to your question directly by [edit]ing it, instead of commenting.

EDIT: The following formula works too (why didn't I think of this sooner?):
=CHOOSECOLS(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({'Form Responses 1'!A1:A,PROPER('Form Responses 1'!B1:B),'Form Responses 1'!C1:C}, "select min(Col1), Col2, min(Col3), count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 order by min(Col1) label Col2 'Games', min(Col3) 'Weblink', count(Col2) 'Total'", 1)), 2, 3, 4)

It's the same as the alternative formula (see below), but with the rows in the order of submission to the form. The same notes as below apply.

You can use the following formula:
= LET(responses, ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER('Form Responses 1'!B2:B)),
  games, ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(responses)),
  { "Game", "Weblink", "Count";
    ARRAYFORMULA({
      IFERROR(VLOOKUP(games, {responses, 'Form Responses 1'!C2:C}, {1,2}, 0)),
      IF(games<>"", COUNTIF('Form Responses 1'!B2:B, games),)
    })
  })

Output:

A few notes:

if there are different links for the same game, the above formula will only keep one of them (the first one) - please do comment if you expect a different behaviour;
the last column, containing the drop-downs, is not generated by the formula, so you would need to add it manually (but you already have);
names written differently, even if referring to the same game, will be treated as separate games - e.g. Mario Bros and Mariobros; the only exception being case sensitivity - e.g. Halo 2 and halo 2 will count as the same game.
you won't be able to use a filter to sort the data. This is because there is a bug by which the built-in sorting of created filters doesn't work with array formulae. So the games will appear in the order they have been submitted to the form.1

Alternative
If you didn't need the drop-down, you could use the QUERY function, simplifying the formula to:
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({PROPER('Form Responses 1'!B1:B),'Form Responses 1'!C1:C}, "select Col1, min(Col2), count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc label Col1 'Games', min(Col2) 'Weblink', count(Col1) 'Total'", 1))

The ARRAYFORMULA and PROPER are there to make the query case-insensitive.
In this case, the same notes as above apply, except that now the games will appear ordered by the total number of times they have been suggested, with the most cited game at the top (but this can be changed).
The issue with the last formula (the first one I suggested), if you want to include the drop-down lists, is the infamous dynamic vs static data alignment2.

1 A script (Google Apps Script) could be used to circumvent this issue.
2 See this question and its answer; and this thread.
References
QUERY - ARRAYFORMULA - PROPER - LET - UNIQUE - IFERROR - VLOOKUP - IF - COUNTIF - CHOOSECOLS

Thanks for the reply! I'll try this out tomorrow when I'm back at my home computer!

Hi!
So I had a chance to check out the formula you posted. It was near enough perfect. Only issue I encountered is that when an entry moves in ranking, so for example in your screenshot if AoE got a second entry, columns A,B and C correctly move with updated totals, but Column D remains as it was. So in the example that AoE now is at the top it has the status of approved that Hades had before.

@Jww243 yep, that's totally my bad! Updated my answer. Hope that works.
